# ffmpeg memory increase when Playing a UDP-MJPEG-Stream

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, arm

im reading a udp-mjpeg-stream with the ffmpeg-API. When i read and display the Stream with an ARM-Processor i have 2 Problems:
1- The Applikation is too slow and there is a big delay between network cam and displayed video.
2- the memory usage increases every time when i call the function av_read_frame().

The Source code

```
const char *cam1_url = "udp://192.168.1.1:1234";
 AVCodec *pCodec;
 AVFrame *pFrame, *pFrameRGB;
 AVCodecContext *pCodecCon;
 AVDictionary *pUdpStreamOptions = NULL;
 AVInputFormat *pMjpegFormat = av_find_input_format("mjpeg");
 av_dict_set(&pUdpStreamOptions, "fifo_size", "5000000", 0);
 av_register_all();
 avdevice_register_all();
 avcodec_register_all();
 avformat_network_init();
 AVFormatContext *pFormatCont = avformat_alloc_context();
 if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCont,cam1_url,pMjpegFormat,&pUdpStreamOptions) < 0)
 {
   cout << "!! Error !! - avformat_open_input(): failed to open input URL" << endl;
 }

 if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCont,NULL) < 0)
 {
   cout << "!! Error !! - avformat_find_stream_info(), Failed to retrieve stream info" << endl;
 }

 av_dump_format(pFormatCont, 0, cam1_url, 0);

 int videoStream;
 for(int i=0; i< pFormatCont->nb_streams; i++)
 {
    if(pFormatCont->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        videoStream=i;
        cout << " videoStream = " << videoStream << endl;
    }
 }
 pCodecCon = pFormatCont->streams[videoStream]->codec;
 pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCon->codec_id);
 if(NULL == pCodec)
 {
   cout << "couldnt find codec" << endl;
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 if(avcodec_open2(pCodecCon,pCodec,NULL) < 0)
 {
    cout << "!! Error !! - in avcodec_open2()" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 uint8_t *frameBuffer;
 int numRxBytes = 0;
 AVPixelFormat pFormat =AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24;
 int width_rgb = (int)((float)pCodecCon->width);
 int height_rgb = (int)((float)pCodecCon->height);
 numRxBytes = avpicture_get_size(pFormat,width_rgb,height_rgb);
 frameBuffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(numRxBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));
 avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pFrameRGB, frameBuffer, pFormat,width_rgb,height_rgb);
  AVPacket rx_pkt; // received packet
 int frameFinished = 0;
 struct SwsContext *imgConvertCtx;
 av_init_packet(&rx_pkt);
 while(av_read_frame(pFormatCont, &rx_pkt) >= 0)
 {
   if(rx_pkt.stream_index == videoStream)
   {  
      av_frame_free(&pFrame);
      pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

      av_frame_free(&pFrameRGB);
      pFrameRGB = av_frame_alloc();

      avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCon, pFrame, &frameFinished,&rx_pkt);

      if(frameFinished)
      {

        imgConvertCtx = sws_getCachedContext(NULL, pFrame->width,pFrame->height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUVJ420P,width_rgb,height_rgb,AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL,NULL);

        sws_scale(imgConvertCtx, ((AVPicture*)pFrame)->data, ((AVPicture*)pFrame)->linesize, 0, pCodecCon->height, ((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB)->data, ((AVPicture *)pFrameRGB)->linesize);

        av_frame_unref(pFrame);
        av_frame_unref(pFrameRGB);
      }
   }
   av_free_packet(&rx_pkt);
   av_packet_unref(&rx_pkt);
 }
 //cvDestroyWindow("Cam1Video");
 av_free_packet(&rx_pkt);
 avcodec_close(pCodecCon);
 av_free(pFrame);
 av_free(pFrameRGB);
 avformat_close_input(&pFormatCont);
```

I have read, the reason could be that the ffmpeg-Libs saves the incomming frames in the cache but the arm-processor isnt fast enough to process them. After like 4 minutes the system craches.

How could i solve the Problem.

one option could be to tell ffmpeg to act as frame grabber, also to read frames in real time, with the flag "-re". How can i set this Flag in the c++ source code. Or can anybody help me to solve that Problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: What actual machine are you running this on (for comparison I have an "ARM processor" in front of me which is a tiny microcontroller with 1KB of RAM; I also have one at work which is a multi-GHz multi-core server-class box with 128GB), and with what kind of OS? Seeing that alloc/free in a loop makes me think of heap fragmentation - how big are the compressed/uncompressed frames?

Comment: I have a imx6 dual arm processor (Sabre automotive from freescale) with 2GB Ram. The OS is Linux Yocto Poky with Kernel 3.14. I have the same Problem with ubuntu. i tried it without alloc/free, also just the function av_read_frame() with  av_free_packet(&rx_pkt). The same Problem. On a ubuntu-host system it worked better, but not on the embedded system. Im receiving 1024x768 jpeg Frames

Comment: OK, so we're in the realm of "real computer" rather than resource-constrained things - that rules out a whole class of potential problems. Have you run it under Valgrind to check for any obvious leaks?

Comment: On the real computer the memory increases till 930 MB and then no more. On the embedded-pc thats too much when i use 2 cameras. i think flushing of the internal cashe of ffmpeg (in AVFormatContext) would solve the problem. when i use avformat_close_input(&pFormatCont) the memory is released. is there any way to seek the last frame and delete all others or to minimize the memory usage?. I have read some articles for this case, i think there is no memory leak. ffmpeg uses just too much memory

Comment: that is interesant: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.video.ffmpeg.libav.user/580